# Variance of the estimate

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, variance, least-squares

I needed assistance with the following proof.  I truly appreciate your assistance.  It is the final line following "Prove that" that I don't understand.  Here we go:

We generate a sample of n=50 observations from a model using uniformly spaced design points:

t${}_{i}$=(2i-1)/100, i= 1, 2... 50.

normally distributed random errors (or $\epsilon$) with $\sigma$ =0.2 and u(t) = t + 0.5exp$\{$-50(t-0.5)${}^{2}$$\}$

A simple linear regression was fitted to the data using least square.  This gives an estimated mean function of the form:

$\hat{u}$(t) =  b${}_{0}$${}_{ }$+ b${}_{1}$(t - $\bar{t}$)  with:

b${}_{1}$= $\mathrm{\sum}$y${}_{i }$(t${}_{i}$ - $\bar{t}$) /$\mathrm{\sum}$( t${}_{i}$ -  $\bar{t}$)${}^{2}$

b${}_{0 }$=$\bar{y}$

$\bar{t}$ = 1/n$\mathrm{\sum}$ t${}_{i}$

$\bar{y}$ =1/n$\mathrm{\sum}$y${}_{i}$

so far so good!

Prove that:

Var($\hat{u}$(t)) = $\sigma$${}^{2}$ [ 1/n  + (t - $\bar{t}$)${}^{2 }$/ $\mathrm{\sum}$(t${}_{i}$ -  $\bar{t}$)${}^{2}$]

Comment: Do you know how to find the covariance matrix of $(b_0, b_1)$?

Comment: no other information is available other than the one stated in the original problem.  however,  covariance of the estimators can be computed from first principles to the best of my knowledge.  I can provide you the derivation if you like. thanks

Comment: The derivation has appeared in many threads on this site, thank you.  But since you know how to find that matrix, and $\hat u(t)$ is a linear function of $(b_0, b_1)$, you're practically done.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I will work out the proof and try to post it as concisely as possible.

Comment: Please don't post the answer within the question--that renders it a non-question.  You may post the answer within the "Your Answer" textbox below.

Answer (score 1):

Proof follows from the following:

Cov( b${}_{0}$${}_{ }$, b${}_{1})$ = 0

Var(b${}_{0}$${}_{ }$) = $\sigma$${}^{2}$/n

and

Var(b${}_{1}$) =  $\sigma$${}^{2}$(t - $\bar{t}$)${}^{2 }$/ $\mathrm{\sum}$(t${}_{i}$ -  $\bar{t}$)${}^{2}$